# How to Implement a LiveReloaded Development Web Server in Python

Tags: python, websocket, webserver

I'm in a bit of a pickle. I'm working on tiny little static site generator, and I am getting to the point where it would be useful to have a development server available through my tool. So I would like to:

- Run a local server
- Update files when there is an update
- Automatically refresh the browser once the updated file has been processed

But I'm not really sure what would be the best way to go about this. I have been looking at using the standard Python web server or Twisted for the server and Watchdog for the updating files, but I am not entirely sure yet. Also, I have no idea how to go about 'refreshing' the page. I have seen the Selenium driver, but I think using that would be a little overkill for what I want, especially since it will require more (non-Python) dependencies. I have also been reading about websockets, but I am not entirely sure how I could fit them into this problem.

So, what do you think would be a good way to go about something like this? Or perhaps a tool like this already exists that I could just add as a dependency to my project... Either way, I would like to hear your ideas.

Comment: For updating the Browser i maybe would use the same method as Microsoft did for vs...  inject a js file into your webpage that opens a websocket to the Server and listens for the Command to reload...

Comment: Could you throw me a link to something on that topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For refreshing the Browser I would recommend you to Check out websockets and than inject a js file at the bottom of your html Page. A websocket Implementation could be:

[Simple Websocket Serverfor Python](https://github.com/dpallot/simple-websocket-server/blob/master/README.md)

Microsoft did this with BrowserLink in VS:

[Browser Link](https://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link)

The js Script to inject could be something Simple like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var socket = new Websocket(url to server);
socket.onmessage = function(e){
if(e.data == "reload"){
location.reload();
}
};
</script>
```